# Create a HyperV disk from an existing folder

Tags: hyper-v

I want to create a virtual disk to attach to a hyper-v VM. This disk will be used to store a lot of files (around eight GB's worth) and will be attached to a hyper V VM.

I don't want to waste time creating the disk, then copying all eight gigs of worth of files then attaching the VM.

Is there a way to create a disk image and have its contents be a folder I specify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create VHD just from partition not folder.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx